# is it possible to visualize coronavirus infection and what type of assays are routinely used?

Tags: histology, coronavirus, fluorescent-microscopy

There has been some electron micrograph of SARS-COV-2 published; but are there any fluorescent/ confocal-fluorescent image of them? or is it possible to do them?  I know that viruses are usually much smaller than capacity of light microscope but I think by using any immunofluorescent probe or [FISH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence_in_situ_hybridization) technique it is possible to visualise the locations occurance of the virus in cell or tissue. At least [one website](https://thenativeantigencompany.com/visualising-viruses-with-immunofluorescence-microscopy/) says it is possible to visualise viral infections using fluorescence techniques.

Now is there any such image for SARS-COV-2, and is it possible to take?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for an image is not posing a biological problem.

Comment: should i delete the question?

Comment: It could be reformulated as a biological question: is it possible to visualize viral infections and what type of assays are routinely used?

Comment: Thank you I will do such change in language; still the question remains the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have an antibody against the viral proteins you can do an immuno staining followed by fluorescence imaging. For this type of technique you would need a very specific antibody. I am not aware that this exist at the moment and I don't think anyone had the time to do it for immunostaining purposes.

For FISH it would depend on the genomic nature of the virus (ssRNA, ssDNA, dsRNA, dsDNA), again you would need specific probes to capture it. Again specific is key.

EDIT 01.04.2020: This group says they have found specific antibodies https://www.centivax.com/covid19

Comment: Okay then its not available yet. No, I have not facilities to work with virus.

Comment: As far as I know it has not been done but who knows things are going extremely fast these days it is hard to keep track of all preprints and publications.